# how to upload Files to Alfresco via Email?

Tags: repository, alfresco, alfresco-share

I wanted to upload files via email in Alfresco. 
I am using alfresco community 5.2
I have added inbound email properties in alfresco-global.properties file
and i have followed all the steps and
I sent an email as explained in below links
But I am not able to receive any files in my alfresco

I have referred the links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p17GkHsLdmc

http://keytocontent.blogspot.in/2010/05/upload-files-to-alfresco-via-email.html

Steps I have followed
1. set the properties in global properties

```
email.inbound.enabled=true
email.server.enabled=true
email.server.port=25
email.server.domain=vikash-laptop.com
email.inbound.unknownUser=anonymous
email.server.allowed.senders=.*
```

2. created a user named as hello1
   email id=> hello1@vikash-laptop.com
   added this user into EMAIL_Contributors group
3. Created a site named as test site
     created a folder in Document Library>>Dropoff and 
     applied aspect email aliasable
     added alias properties as dropoff
   so the my email address will be dropoff@vikash-laptop.com

tried to send email to dropoff@vikash-laptop.com
and hello1@vikash-laptop.com both

Still i am not receiving any files which i have attached in email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded smtp mail sender and it is working. and now i am able to receive email attachments in alfresco.

Answer (score 5):

How did you try and send an email to vikash-laptop.com? You need to make sure the host name you are specifying (vikash-laptop.com) is going to resolve to the IP address of your alfresco server (I assume running on your laptop).

You also need to make sure that your mail client will resolve that domain correctly and can connect to the alfresco server. For example, if you were going to try and send an email from gmail, that would have problems unless vikash-laptop.com was a registered domain so that the gmail servers could resolve it and access port 25 on that machine from the internet.

If you just want to do a simple test on your laptop without a mail client where alfresco is running you can just telnet to the alfresco host and try and connect to that port (google "test smtp telnet" for a lot of suggestions) and see that it is listening on port 25 as you configured it and that you can send test email.

Comment: yes, i have specified host name in hosts file as
**127.0.0.1 vikash-laptop.com**

I have tried by telnet and It is working.

I tried to send email using gmail.

Comment: Unless you can edit the host file on every one of Google's servers, that won't help you with sending via gmail!

Comment: thank you, it would be more helpful If can you please explain to me that what I should have to do next?

Comment: You should use a mail client from your machine. Thunderbird, or a simple smtp client like theses : http://www.snapfiles.com/get/smtpmailsender.html, https://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/utilitiesprogs/sendsmtp.htm. In it, you'll have to put your alfresco smtp ip + port.

Comment: Thanks a lot Akah,
I have downloaded smtp mail sender and it is working.
and now i am able to receive email attachments in alfresco